# How to change/update ids of a div included in list

Tags: jquery, html

i want to "update" html ids, after i deleted one list in my (Node-RED)-Application.

Example:

Before: (The HTML Code is buildup dynamicly)

```
<li>
    <div>
        <select class="Row" id="Row1_1"> <option> .... </option> </select>
        <input class="spinner" id="Row2_1">
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div>
        <select class="Row" id="Row1_2"> <option> .... </option> </select>
        <input class="spinner" id="Row2_2">
    </div>
</li>           
<li>
    <div>
        <select class="Row" id="Row1_3"> <option> .... </option> </select>
        <input class="spinner" id="Row2_3">
    </div>
</li>
```

After: (after i delete a list in my Application the ids are still the same)

```
<li>
    <div>
        <select class="Row" id="Row1_1"> <option> .... </option> </select>
        <input class="spinner" id="Row2_1">
    </div>
</li>           
<li>
    <div>
        <select class="Row" id="Row1_3"> <option> .... </option> </select>
        <input class="spinner" id="Row2_3">
    </div>
</li>
```

Now i want to change the ids that they are continious again.

(1_1,2_1 following by 1_2,2_2 and NOT 1_3,2_3)

I already have:

```
$("#containerID").children().each(function() {  //get all elements
        var list=this;   //every list contains one li-element!
        //here i want to upfdate all ids!!
        //something like:  $('div').attr('id','id_new');
});
```

How can i iterate through all elements??

Answer (score 0):

You can use index of element in each method to concatenate with static string for creating ID value :

```
$("#containerID .row").each(function(i){
   $(this).attr('id','Row1_'+(i+1)); //as index are 0 based
   $(this).next().attr('id', 'Row2_' +(i+1));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Capture the `index` argument in the each to give you the count, then set the id of `.Row` and `.spinner` accordingly.

```
$("#containerID").children().each(function(index){
    var count = index+1; // zero based so add 1

    $(this).find('.Row').prop('id', 'Row1_' + count);
    $(this).find('.spinner').prop('id', 'Row2_' + count);
});
```

For seting an element id, `.prop()` is more appropriate then `.attr()`.

Comment: Hi, this won't work. In one class are several ids. This is a short Version of my code. Sorry for the mistake.